# ¿Cómo saber si un archivo regular existe, pero solo para un periodo en bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Supongamos que el archivo existe:

```
if [  -f "archivo" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: Archivo con informacion de datos existe "

fi
```

supongamos que "archivo" es una tabla con varias filas de registros y cada registro tiene una misma "fecha", como puedo hacer para que el programa me muestre el archivo solamente ocupando el campo de "fecha"

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir _para un período específico_?

Comment: No será más bien que quieres "ver" el contenido del archivo, pero solo la columna "fecha"? Si es así, puedes utilizar el comando "cut"

Comment: no, quiero validar que el archivo exista solo para el periodo ingresado(fecha)